# What is a Linker Map Address ()

Tags: c#, xna-4.0, windows, visual-studio, microsoft

I need to know how to execute a linker map address and use a draw method in xna 4.0 to for example in c#

My subfolder has this in it

textures
models
sounds
ui
scripts
shaders
linker map address

```
public void Draw()

{


// I need to execute my assets with the linker map address.


}
```

Comment: I know that doom 3 uses a linker map address method for loading maps in the mod menu so Why cant this be the same.

Comment: can you give some more details? Where are you seeing this issue?

Comment: That's just it I have no issue its just getting my map to load in my xna main menu I select level select option and nothing happens So I need to bind these assets and execute the linker map address in my draw method but how do i do that

Answer (score 1):

So looking at your other post on the subject, it looks like this is relating to doom. Doom uses maps with the extension .map. However, many programs use the .map extension. What you are seeing is Visual studio thinks that that file is a file it knows.

If you want info on loading/using Doom maps, see

- https://www.iddevnet.com/doom3/maps.php
- https://modwiki.xnet.fi/MAP_(file_format)

Given that there are only so many 3 letter combinations, something as common as .map will get reused by different programs for different things. Windows will not necessarily give you the right answer as to what that file is